# VSCode find references fast Angular without search

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there any add-on that makes it possible with 2 clicks to navigate to the usage of a method from Angular TS file to HTML template?
Like in IntelliJ:
[image: IntelliJ go to reference]

In all questions similar to this they suggest to use find in all files - ctrl + shift + f in VSCode -, which is fast, but I think that IntelliJ's find usages - ctrl + click - is faster because it is not a simple text search, but rather a search for method format.

Comment: right click - find all references

Comment: thank you, I can't understand why I didn't find it.